# Since nucleons are not elementary particles more, how we call nucleons and electrons together now?

Tags: elementary-particles

In the time before the discovery of quarks the nucleon particle proton and neutron together with electrons were called elementary particles.

It's a little bit boring to have only the possibility to describe protons, neutrons and electrons together as nucleons and electrons. Which description one can use for all three particles together?

Comment: Electrons *are* elementary particles.

Comment: @dmckee: I corrected this.

Comment: I don't understand your question - why should you call them anything else than "nucleons and electrons"?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Jimmy360: I tried to say it better.

Comment: If you're looking for a single term that includes all of them, "subatomic particle" might be a good choice.

Comment: @Asher: I would not expect these emotions. It's just a question about naming conventions. Your comment is the most logical name and if you don't mind please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no collective noun that includes only the electron, proton and neutron and excludes all other particles. Possibly you could use *stable subatomic particles*, but the neutron is only stable when it's in a nucleus so that doesn't really work (and I suppose it should include photons and neutrinos).

As ACuriousMind suggests in a comment, *nucleons and electrons* is the most concise term I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

We can describe them as quark combinations. A neutron is a u-d-d and a proton is a u-u-d. Also, by charge, we have +1, -1, 0.

Comment: You left out what an electron is.

Comment: @LDC3 just a fundamental particle